# Time function not working in c

Tags: c, datetime

I used the following code segment to get the system time. But it results in a segmentation fault. Please help.

```
printf("Time : %s\n", System("time"));
return 0;
```

Comment: What does your manual say is the return type of the `System()` (*uppercase 'S'???! this is not Standard C*) function?

Comment: If you're using the library call `system()` it will return an integer, which contains the return-value of the executed call, not the output of the program. If you want the current system-time have a look at `time()`,`localtime()` and `strftime()`.

Comment: Did your compiler give you any warnings about the printf format specifier? For example `"warning: format ‘%s’ expects type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’"`. If so, don't ignore the compiler warnings; they're trying to tell you something. If not, you might want to turn on warnings or get a better compiler :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code instead:

```
time_t t;
time(&t);
printf("%s", ctime(&t));
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean `system()` rather than `System()`.

You seem to expect that `system()` would return a string containing whatever the command has printed to the terminal. It does not do that. In fact, `system()` returns the exit code of the child process.

The easiest way to get the current time is by using the `time()` function:

```
NAME
       time - get time in seconds

SYNOPSIS
       #include <time.h>

       time_t time(time_t *t);

DESCRIPTION
       time()  returns  the  time  since  the  Epoch (00:00:00 UTC, January 1,
       1970), measured in seconds.

       If t is non-NULL, the return value is also stored in the memory pointed
       to by t.
```

Answer (score 2):

The system() function returns an exit status (an int), not a string. Calling `system("time")` prints the time to stdout. If that's what you want, just use

```
 system("time");
```

You get a segfault because the int 0, when interpreted as a pointer for printf's `%s` is a NULL pointer. Dereferencing NULL pointers is undefined behavior and a segmentation fault is one possibility for such undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The [system() function](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) returns an integer, while `%s` indicates that you want to print a string. The system function does not return the result of the `time` program, but the exit value.